# Angular 6 - How to process all Components together? Not individually

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-components, angular2-components, angular6

My website needs to publish advertising. The advertising I receive from the AdServer. I currently have a component to do this job. It works like this:

```
<div>
  ...
  <app-advertising adPos="x22"></app-advertising>
  ...
  <app-advertising adPos="Top"></app-advertising>
  ...
  <app-advertising adPos="x94"></app-advertising>
  ...
</div>
```

In my Angular v6 component currently **I need to process each tag individually. It means (in this example) 3 different requests to the AdServer.**

But our AdServer also supports 1 request with all adPos concatenated. But to do that, I need to read all components tags and make just 1 request for all of them. How can I do that using Angular 2+?

Comment: can you add more code on how you're currently submit request for the Ad?

Comment: @chau-tran please see my own answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to rewrite your code. Does each app-advertising make a request to the AdServer?
If so, you can make a service that receives the array and query the AdServer once (pseucod-pseudo-code):

```
class YourService {

   queryAdserver(arrayOfIds): Observable<Array> {
     // query the AdServerService
   }
}
```

your parent component use this service

```
adServerData: any/ // I don't know the Type here, so I set any
constructor(yourService: YourService) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.yourService.queryAdserver(['x22', 'Top', 'x94'])
   .subscribe( data => {
      this.adServerData = data;
   })
}
```

and the template use this data and pass the data, instead of the id

```
<app-advertising [data]="adServerData[0]"></app-advertising>
...
<app-advertising [data]="adServerData[1]"></app-advertising>
...
<app-advertising [data]="adServerData[2]"></app-advertising>
```

Note that this is some sort of pseudo-code, explaining the main idea of how to query only once this AdServer service and then use the data and pass to the component you have written, turning the `app-advertising` component into a 'dumb' one, that only receives data and render it.

Comment: Good approach. I will try to implement it. In this case, I'll have to touch all the parent-components that have child-components with advertising, right? In this case the website is big, with many differents parent-components like Home, Article, Video, Galery, Sections, etc, etc. And each one of these have child-components.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer after trying different approaches.

- Considering that the component `advertising.component` has different ad positions and are used in different templates (like `article.component.html`, `header.component.html`, `video.component.html`, etc). For example:

  ```
  <!-- in article component, this one: -->
  <app-advertising adPos="x22" adDisp="mobile"></app-advertising>
  <app-advertising adPos="x23" adDisp="mobile"></app-advertising>

  <!-- in video component, this one: -->
  <app-advertising adPos="Position1" adDisp="desktop"></app-advertising>
  <app-advertising adPos="x94" adDisp="desktop"></app-advertising>

  <!-- in header component, this one: -->
  <app-advertising adPos="x95" adDisp="desktop"></app-advertising>
  ```
- *Apparently* Angular uses a singleton pattern and all components/templates make use of the same instance of the advertising service. So, in my `advertising.service` I created a `private listPos: Map<string, AdvertisingComponent> = new Map();` where I add all the advertising positions.

  ```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import {AdItemModel, AdModel} from './ad.model';
  import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
  import {AdvertisingComponent} from './advertising.component';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class AdvertisingService {

    /**
     * List of positions(advertising) and component instances.
     * @type {Map<string, AdvertisingComponent>}
     */
    private listPos: Map<string, AdvertisingComponent> = new Map();

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {HttpClient} http (injectable)
     */
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    /**
     * Add position and component instance in the map.
     * Example of position: x22, x95, Position1, etc.
     * @param {string} adPos
     * @param {AdvertisingComponent} element
     * @return void
     */
    public registerPos(adPos: string, element: AdvertisingComponent): void {
      this.listPos.set(adPos, element);
      console.log('Add: ' + Array.from(this.listPos.keys()));
    }

    /**
     * Get ads from AdServer. Jsonp request.
     * @param {number} sleepMs
     * @return void
     */
    public getAds(sleepMs: number): void {

      setTimeout(() => { // wait for DOM rendering

        /**
         * Check if advertising position exist
         */
        if (this.listPos.size === 0) {
          return;
        }

        const url = 'http://your-ad-server-url-here@' + Array.from(this.listPos.keys());

        this.http.jsonp<AdModel>(url, '_RM_HTML_CALLBACK_').subscribe((response: AdModel) => {

          // process all ads
          this.process(response.Ad);

          // clean map
          this.listPos.clear();

        });

      }, sleepMs);

    }

    /**
     * Process list of advertising and publish them in their respecive position in the templates.
     * @param {AdItemModel[]} items
     * @return void
     */
    private process(items: AdItemModel[]): void {

      items.forEach((value: AdItemModel) => {

        /**
         * Get the 'AdvertisingComponent' instance from the Map and print the advertising there.
         * @type {V | undefined}
         */
        const adComponentInst: AdvertisingComponent = this.listPos.get(value.Pos);
        if (adComponentInst !== null) {
          adComponentInst.ad = value.SOMETHING; // the value object depends on your AdServer
        }

      });

    }

  }
  ```
- In my `advertising.component` the only thing I do is to add the position (`adPos`) parameter tag and the instance of the component to the service `Map`.

  ```
  import {Component, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
  import {AdvertisingService} from './advertising.service';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-advertising',
    templateUrl: './advertising.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./advertising.component.css']
  })
  export class AdvertisingComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() adPos: string;
    @Input() adDisp: string;
    public ad = '';

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {AdvertisingService} adService
     */
    constructor(private adService: AdvertisingService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      /**
       * Register the current position and instance in the Advertising Service
       */
      this.adService.registerPos(this.adPos, this);
    }

  }
  ```
- And in my `AppComponent`, when the event `NavigationEnd` is captured, I call the `advertising.service` to get from the AdServer ALL the positions together (making just ONE REQUEST), and add all the results in the respective instance position.

  ```
  import {Component} from '@angular/core';
  import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
  import {AdvertisingService} from './advertising/advertising.service';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {

    title = 'Website Beta';

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {Router} router
     * @param {AdvertisingService} adService
     */
    constructor(private router: Router, private adService: AdvertisingService) {

      /**
       * Detect route changes
       */
      this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
        //  console.log(event.constructor.name);
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

          /**
           * Execute advertising after a few miliseconds
           */
          this.adService.getAds(500);

        }
      });

    }

  }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Put your ads in an array then loop.

Something like this:

```
<app-advertising *ngFor="let ad of ads"
[adPos]="ad">
</app-advertising>
```

Comment: The problem is that the component tags `<app-advertising>` are located in different templates/locations. It's not sequential.